# How hide all table have same id except the last one add

Tags: jquery, html

When selected by Select option, it is to change the table different information but with the same identifier, I want, when change happens works to hide the old table and the new table shows.

This is my jquery code:

```
$("#testing").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test_gets.php",
        data: { country: selectedCountry }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if ($("#inner_content1").length !== 0) { $("#search_b").hide(1000) };
        $("#inner_content1").append(data + "<br/>");
    });
});
```

This page test_gets.php contains a table to be displayed:

```
<form dir="rtl" method="POST"  class="search_b" id="search_b">
```

And This is part of the form that occurs through change:

```
 <select name="testing" class="testing" id="testing">
```

In this case, when I change, it hides the old and the new shows, but when I change again, the old shows and new shows , I just want to show the new.

I hope to be well understood my question
Any idea about that ?

Comment: Having same ID on more than one element is invalid HTML, you should use `class` attribute

Comment: use this $('#search_b').not(':last').hide(1000);

Comment: @B-and-P its just one element show and hide

Comment: @jilesh Good idea but not work